# Cakephp - Baking custom models

Tags: cakephp, model

I need to bake a large project but a requirement is each model has its schema listed at the top as a multi-line comment.

Any ideas ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start in your [PATH]/cake/console/templates/classes/model.ctp file.

Manually connect to the database using an old-fashioned php connect string.

Pull the table structure in a "describe" query.

Loop through, print out the table structure in comments.

cake bake...